# Java pattern using for loop, stuck in the last part

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Here is my code, I am trying to get a specific pattern but I ended up with an unexpected pattern.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i * 2; j++)
        {
            if (i != 3)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }

        for(int k = 13; k > i * 2; k--)
        {   
            System.out.print("*");  
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

I am getting this:

```
*************
  ***********
    *********
*************
        *****
```

When I should be getting this:

```
*************
  ***********
    *********
  ***********
*************
```

Anyone can help me with this one? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging through it to see if it's going through the loops as you expect it to? Once you do that it should be clear to you what should change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that you print is a sequence of space '' and asterisks '`*`' characters. Its length is always 13. So the sum of of `spaces` and `stars` must be 13.

Whenever a line is printed 2 spaces are added to the line and 2 stars are removed, until you reach a point where the reverse operation is happened (the point is 9 stars).

This code prints that pattern.

```
public class Pattern{

    private static final int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 13;
    private static final int MIN_LINE_LENGTH = 9;
    private static final int DIFFERENCE = 2;
    private static final int LINES = 5;

    private static final String SPACE = " ";
    private static final String STAR = "*";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPattern();
    }

    private static void printPattern(){
        int spaces = 0;
        int stars = MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
        boolean reverse = false;

        for (int i=0; i<LINES; i++) {
            printLine(spaces,stars);

            if (stars == MIN_LINE_LENGTH) {
                reverse = true;
            }

            if (reverse == false) {
                spaces+=DIFFERENCE;
                stars-=DIFFERENCE;  
            }else{
                spaces-=DIFFERENCE;
                stars+=DIFFERENCE;
            }       
        }
    }

    private static void printLine(int spaces, int stars){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<spaces+stars; i++) {
            if (i<spaces) {
                builder.append(SPACE);      
            }else{
                builder.append(STAR);               
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure that will work, but I wanted to use the least code possible without having to create methods for it. I am a beginner so most of the logic you used is new for me and I don't quite seem to understand everything. I still appreciate your time to help me. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Hugelevin. By the way, I've split the code in small methods just to be cleared and more understandable. On the way you will learn to break problems into small ones and eventually write your code somehow like this above, so people will understand it. 

Never forget that you don't write code just for yourself, you write code to be read by others, just like I did (tried at least). Cheers!

Comment: By the way if you have any questions about the above code snippet just ask here in the comment section.